# How to retrieve a checkbox checked from MySQL array?

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql set up like this

### MySQL

**Table: gallery**

```
+-------------+------------+
| galleryname | coverphoto |
+-------------+------------+
```

**Table: multigalleries**

```
+-------------+-----------+
| galleryname | galleries |
+-------------+-----------+
```

I am using a checkbox array from php to place galleries into `multigalleries.galleries` like `gallery1,gallery2,gallery3`. All of that works fine, the only thing i cant figure out is, when I pull the list of `gallery.galleryname` and reference it with `multigalleries.galleries`, how can i return a checked state if it exists in `multigalleries.galleries`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT// ACTUAL CODE IM USING IF IT WILL HELP

```
$con = mysql_connect($host,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($databasename, $con);
$query = "SELECT galleries.gallery, galleries.coverphoto, multigalleries.multigallery,            multigalleries.galleries FROM galleries, multigalleries";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo '<div class="gallery" style="background-image:none">';
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="galleriesm[]" value="'.$line[gallery].'">'.      $line[gallery].'';
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: I have tried isinarray as well as joining the table togethar from a select command to say if gallery.galleryname == multigalleries.gallery but its not seeming to work. most of the help I found was relating to a checked state being yes/no or 0/1 not actual values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$a = mysql_query("
    SELECT g.galleryname FROM gallery AS g, multigalleries AS m
    WHERE g.galleryname = 'gallery1' AND FIND_IN_SET(g.galleryname, m.galleries)
");

$b = mysql_fetch_assoc($a);

echo '<input type="checkbox" name="whatever"';

if($b['galleryname'])
{
    echo ' checked="checked"';
}

echo '>';
```

### Edit:

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT g.galleryname, m.galleryname AS name FROM gallery AS g 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT galleryname, galleries FROM multigalleries) AS m ON 
    FIND_IN_SET(g.galleryname, m.galleries)
");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $checked = '';

    if($row['name'])
    {
        $checked = ' checked="checked"';
    }

    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="galleriesm[]" id="'.$row['galleryname'].'" value="'.$row['galleryname'].'"'.$checked.'>
    <label for="'.$row['galleryname'].'">'.$row['galleryname'].'</label>';
}
```

Comment: Can get this to work either, It of course calls the correct values from the database when i echo them, but it wont check the boxes.

Comment: BUT I think this is on the right track! So I will spend the next few pots of coffee on this haha.

Comment: Could you please add your markup to your original question? Because now I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly.

Comment: I added it as per your request.

Comment: I updated my answer. :) Let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: That was it, for some reason it wasnt finding it correctly when I chose g.galleryname to find in set. But when I passed the variables via _get it worked fine. Thanks for taking the time to help!